# Any way to connect two VGA monitors to GeForce 970?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a pair of ancient ViewSonic VE710s VGA monitors that are still going strong (if a little bit filthy!) after more than a decade of use. I recently purchased an MSI GeForce 970. Unfortunately, I didn't realise that unlike my existing 580 GTX, the 970 comes with one each of DVI-D and DVI-I ports instead of 2xDVI-I.

I picked up a cheap DVI-D/VGA adapter from our local hardware shop, but (unsurprisingly) it doesn't work. Actually, if I understand correctly, there's no way these things *can* work, no? Why do they get made?... Anyway,

Is there any way I can connect my two existing VGA monitors to my GeForce 970? Or am I stuck with a single monitor setup like a caveman until some nice shiny new screens arrive?

The motherboard (if it's possibly relevant) is a ASUS® Z97-P. It has a VGA socket on it, but it doesn't appear to be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are halfway there. A plain DVI-I/VGA adapter should work for one of the monitors since [DVI-I outputs an analogue as well as digital signal](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/221/~/what-is-the-difference-between-dvi-i-and-dvi-d%3F).

For the DVI-D output you can get so-called 'active' adapters, which should do a digital-analogue conversion. I haven't used one myself - closest I've got is a Thunderbolt-VGA adapter - so can't make a recommendation for a particular adapter/manufacturer. They will be a little more pricey<sup>1</sup> than a 'dumb' adapter though, so take this into consideration if you are thinking of upgrading those work horses!

**Edit**: Additionally, you might want to check your BIOS to see if your motherboard will support using the integrated graphics as well as your 970. Apparently, it can be found under `Advanced -> System Agent Configuration -> Graphics Configuration`, where you should enable `igpu` and `multi-monitor`. Can't test this myself, but [this Tom's Hardware thread](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2305170/integrated-video-video-card-asus-z97.html) reckons that works for the Z97-A. It's not a z97-P but might be close enough; and it may require installing Intel drivers afterwards.

<sup>1</sup>: There seem to be active converters for around 20 GBP; but as indicated that's no comment on whether they work or not

Comment: I guess I need to get new monitors then. OH WELL :D

Comment: No luck between one DVI-I/VGA adapter and enabling motherboard output? Nonetheless, a new monitor or two will probably be a productivity boon; and you may yet get a few quid back if you stick the old ones on Gumtree/etc :)

Comment: @IainGalloway Not that I want to put you off new shiny (go for it!); but in case other folks are reading the comments- DVI-VGA dumb adapters should only be a couple of quid as they're relatively simple and don't do active conversion.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. Yes, DVI-I/VGA adapters are fine. DVI- **D** /VGA adapders are expensive. I couldn't find an easy way to allow the 970 GTX to drive the motherboard VGA socket. For posterity, I believe I *could* get a reasonably cheap *DisplayPort/VGA* converter (or two) and drive the monitor that way.